# jquery datepicker on a multi input form

Tags: jquery, dynamic, datepicker

I have dynamically created a webpage with few input fields for dates.
These field have the same class but different ids.

These input fields are populated from the mysql so I don't know the id of the clicked field off hand.

I want to pop up a datepicker when a user click on these fields to edit them.

I have used the code below to compare the start date with the end date on every row but I am getting an error: 
        "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined"

```
    <input type="text" class="selStart" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="selStart'.$a.'" value="'.$row['starts'].'" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" class="selEnd" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="selEnd'.$a.'" value="'.$row['ends'].'" readonly="readonly" />

    <input type="text" class="selStart" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="selStart'.$a.'" value="'.$row['starts'].'" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" class="selEnd" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="selEnd'.$a.'" value="'.$row['ends'].'" readonly="readonly" />

    $(".selStart").datepicker();

    $(".selEnd").datepicker();
```

Comment: Could you include your HTML part as well.

Comment: It would be easier if you could reproduce the error in a fiddle

Comment: @Outlooker, my html is dynamic, so in reality I don't know what the hard code would be at the time. I know that my jquery code is working if I give it exact ids as I am using this piece of code in the other sections of my page. I think that because I am calling the element by it's class name and I have few of them with the same call name the datepicked can't function... I am not sure!

Comment: So ur 2 input fields have the same ids rit..??

Comment: @Outlooker, no different ids created dynamically...

Comment: could you copy paste the rendered html from the console by inspecting it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working fine for me in jsfiddle,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/rLsbv71x/)

If you have trouble in getting the popup may you have not included jQuery UI in your project, or an invalid version of jquery library.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="selStart" id="firstInput" name="selStart" value="" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" class="selEnd" id="secondInput" name="selEnd" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selStart").datepicker();
    $(".selEnd").datepicker(); 
});
```

Comment: No the pop up was coming up but wouldn't output anything. But, I found the problem, for some reason, it didn't like my naming skim! I changed that and now it works!!! Thank you for your help though!

Comment: okay @Steve , glad it works!!! you can always post your working solution as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I changed my naming skim for the input tags and now it works!